# how to replace angular theme CSS stylesheet for whole app?

Tags: css, angular, theming

First I couldn't import css through index.html and I get MIME type error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOO4.png)
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/pink-bluegrey.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

if i try to import it through angular.json then I can't insert ID tag id="themeAsset".

Reason why I want to add id is because i want to do this from https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

function changeTheme(themeName) {
  document.getElementById('themeAsset').href = `/path/to/my/${themeName}.css`;
}
so i could change style for whole app styles by click instead of adding classes to every component

Comment: <link id="themeAsset" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/pink-bluegrey.css">
This i can't insert through index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrkmhn

I placed my css inside assets folder i.e. myStyles.css

CSS :-

```
.myDiv {
  background-color: black;
}
```

index.html

```
<link id="myLink">
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="myDiv">Css Will Load</div>

<button style="margin-top: 2em" (click)="changeTheme('')">Change Theme</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';


changeTheme(themeName) {
   var elem = document.getElementById('myLink');
   elem.setAttribute('href','./assets/myStyles.css');
   elem.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
   elem.setAttribute('type','text/css');
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but if you check the post, I'm having problem to insert id="themeAsset" to the css file
if I try to add css through index.html
<link id="themeAsset" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/pink-bluegrey.css"> 
I get MIME error

Comment: try putting a extra / in the end of path.

Comment: and shouldn't your css be inside assets folder? as assets is the only pulic repository that gets served in angular?

Comment: Hi I've manage to do it with the workaround when moving it to assets, thanks for the help !

Comment: Vote it as answer please, so others can benefit

Comment: i did. it tells me Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: you can mark it as answer. just click on tick mark. below down arrow.